# STM32 Nucleo board, "crosstalk" between switch buttons

Tags: stm32, switching, button, debounce, crosstalk

There are 3 switch buttons on a regular solderless breadboard each following this diagram:

[image]

Upon pressing any of the buttons, I am getting spurious breakpoint hits inside the ISRs for the other two as well as inside the proper ISR. And multiple times as well, at least two times on each button press. At most 5 or 6 times.

I have noticed pretty much the same behaviour on disconnecting R1 from them, but there is no more of it when the INPUT wire is disconnected from Nucleo board. It is a Nucleo-H745ZI should it matter.

Any clues to what might be going on ?

Values for R1 and C1 tried:

- 1Mohm       & 0.18 uF
- 100 kohm    & 0.33 uF
- 10 kohm     & 4.7 uF

Code:

```
int main()
{
   ....
   
  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
    PinConfig();
  /* USER CODE END 2 */
 
   ....
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN 4 */
void PinConfig()
{
      __HAL_RCC_GPIOB_CLK_ENABLE();

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_15|GPIO_PIN_4;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_FALLING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed= GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_12|GPIO_PIN_3;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = GPIO_PIN_5;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING_FALLING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Speed= GPIO_SPEED_LOW;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI4_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI4_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI15_10_IRQn, 3, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI15_10_IRQn);

//    /* Configure the second CPU (CM4) EXTI line for IT*/
//    HAL_EXTI_D2_EventInputConfig(EXTI_LINE15 , EXTI_MODE_IT,  ENABLE);
//    HAL_EXTI_D2_EventInputConfig(EXTI_LINE5 , EXTI_MODE_IT,  ENABLE);
//    HAL_EXTI_D2_EventInputConfig(EXTI_LINE4 , EXTI_MODE_IT,  ENABLE);
}


void EXTI4_IRQHandler()
{

    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_5);
    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_15);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_4);
}

void EXTI9_5_IRQHandler()
{

    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_4);
    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_15);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_5);
}

void EXTI15_10_IRQHandler()
{

    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_5);
    //__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_PIN_4);
    HAL_GPIO_EXTI_IRQHandler(GPIO_PIN_15);
}
    
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
{
    static bool fOldLeft, fOldRight;

//    if(__HAL_GPIO_EXTI_GET_IT(GPIO_Pin) != RESET)
//    {
//        __HAL_GPIO_EXTI_CLEAR_IT(GPIO_Pin);
//        uint16_t timepass = 0;
//
//        while (++timepass)
//            ;
//    }

    if(GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_15)                 // Left signal
    {
        //if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_15))
        {fLeft = !fLeft;
        fRight = false;}

    } else if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_4) {        // Right signal

        //if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_4))
        {fLeft = false;
        fRight = !fRight;}

    } else if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_5) {        // Cancel/Reset

        if (!HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOB, GPIO_PIN_5))           // falling edge, btn pressed
        {
            fOldLeft = fLeft;
            fOldRight = fRight;
            fLeft = true;
            fRight = true;

        } else {

            fLeft = fOldLeft;
            fRight = fOldRight;
        }
    }

    uiCnt = 349;
}
```

---

*edit1*

Employed this other debounce scheme and it got rid of the crosstalk problem With R3 = 10k and Vcc = 3v3. Still getting (mostly) two calls on the same, proper ISR instead of only one. If you can explain any of this in an answer please do.

[image]

Comment: I would not only focus on the hardware side of the issue... You might want to write a simple test program, perhaps without interrupts but with a simple polling, that will scan all of the inputs and indicate if these were triggered unexpectedly.

Comment: That is the reason you generally don't trigger interrupts with UI buttons. The button contacts bounce and they will bounce no matter what amount of RC filtering there is, as there is always a chance that the button bounces near the input threshold voltage, and since RC makes voltage changes slow to high direction any noise can trigger extra interrupts. Also it is a bad idea to just short capacitors with buttons as there is a huge current spike. The buttons being on a solderless breadboard may couple the current spike to nearby buttons, as wiring can have inductance.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the capacitor. The pin state change interrupt handler should disable itself and enable a debounce timer. After the debounce timer expires, the pin state interrupt handler should get re-enabled.

Since there may be multiple debounce timers needed in parallel, they'd be handled by a single timer and a list of intervals and callees for each.